# To cite something of Association in the author field

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

My Bibtex

```
@ARTICLE{aami,
    title = {Ambulatory electrocardiographs},
    author = {Association for the Advancement of Medical Instrumentation},
    year = {1998},
    address = {Arlington, \uppercase{USA}},
    note = {\uppercase{ANSI/AAMI} EC38:1998}
}
```

I get in IEEE style

[image]

The title field is not shown correctly.
**What should you write for the author field for a publication?**

Comment: The title seems to be right, the author seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `author = {{Association for the Advancement of Medical Instruments}}` should solve the problem.